# Python - How do i build a dictionary from a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary, building

for the class data structures and algorithms at Tilburg University i got a question in an in class test:

build a dictionary from testfile.txt, with only unique values, where if a value appears again, it should be added to the total sum of that productclass.
the text file looked like this, it was not a .csv file:

```
apples,1
pears,15
oranges,777
apples,-4
oranges,222
pears,1
bananas,3
```

so apples will be -3 and the output would be `{"apples": -3, "oranges": 999...}`
in the exams i am not allowed to import any external packages besides the normal: pcinput, math, etc. i am also not allowed to use the internet. 
I have no idea how to accomplish this, and this seems to be a big problem in my development of python skills, because this is a question that is not given in a 'dictionaries in python' video on youtube (would be to hard maybe), but also not given in a expert course because there this question would be to simple.

hope you guys can help!

```
enter code here
from collections import Counter
from sys import exit
from os.path import exists, isfile
##i did not finish it, but wat i wanted to achieve was build a list of the 
strings and their belonging integers. then use the counter method to add 
them together
## by splitting the string by marking the comma as the split point. 

filename = input("filename voor input: ")
if not isfile(filename):
    print(filename, "bestaat niet")
    exit()

keys = []
values = []
with open(filename) as f:
xs = f.read().split()
    for i in xs:
        keys.append([i])
print(keys)
my_dict = {}

for i in range(len(xs)):
    my_dict[xs[i]] = xs.count(xs[i])
print(my_dict)
word_and_integers_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(word_and_integers_dict)

values2 = my_dict.split(",")
    for j in values2:
        print( value2 )
```

the output becomes is this:

```
[['schijndel,-3'], ['amsterdam,0'], ['tokyo,5'], ['tilburg,777'], ['zaandam,5']]
{'zaandam,5': 1, 'tilburg,777': 1, 'amsterdam,0': 1, 'tokyo,5': 1, 'schijndel,-3': 1}
{}
```

so i got the dictionary from it, but i did not separate the values.
the error message is this:

```
 28 values2 = my_dict.split(",") <-- here was the error
 29 for j in values2:
 30     print( value2 )
```

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Did you actually try something?

Comment: Get hands dirty and put some code first :)

Comment: "hope you guys can help!" Sure we can. As long as by "help" you don't mean "provide the complete program". That's something you can pay a programmer for.

Comment: okay after some time i came up with this! sorry for not providing it:

Comment: @StefanBloemheuvel thanks for posting your code. Please explain how it fails, i.e. what result does it produce (or possibly what error gets thrown) and how this differs from what you want.

Comment: "I am also not allowed to use the internet." <- :P

Comment: The error i got was this: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'. and yes @timgeb i really am not allowed to use the internet...

Comment: Well, good thing we're just on the othernet here. Anyway,  'dict' object has no attribute 'split' indicates that a variable you think is a string (which you can split) is actually a dict. Debug your code with print statements.

Comment: Protip: never mention something is homework or for school. People here don't like it and will be hostile.

Comment: @timgeb i got the question last week, so now we are allowed to discuss the results. it was an exam and i failed to answer that question. i am just not allowed to use the internet during the test

Comment: @jdm that's not true. It appears that way because most homework questions are just bad. I.e. no MCVE, no own effort, unclear problem description and possibly "urgent" in the title.

Comment: @StefanBloemheuvel oh I see :)

Comment: @timgeb so i should add print statements during my program to show what the program does?

Comment: @StefanBloemheuvel exactly, that's how you debug.

Comment: okay i have class again till 16:30 and afterwards i will try to do it on my own again with the input from you guys! thanks already for the great support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your code is actually doing, I think you don't know what your variables are containing, but this is an easy problem to solve in Python. Split into a list, split each item again, and count:

```
>>> input = "apples,1 pears,15 oranges,777 apples,-4 oranges,222 pears,1 bananas,3"
>>> parts = input.split()
>>> parts
['apples,1', 'pears,15', 'oranges,777', 'apples,-4', 'oranges,222', 'pears,1', 'bananas,3']
```

Then split again. Behold the list comprehension. This is an idiomatic way to transform a list to another in python. Note that the numbers are strings, not ints yet.

```
>>> strings = [s.split(',') for s in strings]
>>> strings
[['apples', '1'], ['pears', '15'], ['oranges', '777'], ['apples', '-4'], ['oranges', '222'], ['pears', '1'], ['bananas', '3']]
```

Now you want to iterate over pairs, and sum all the same fruits. This calls for a dict:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for fruit, countstr in pairs:
...     if fruit not in result:
...         result[fruit] = 0
...     result[fruit] += int(countstr)
>>> result
{'pears': 16, 'apples': -3, 'oranges': 999, 'bananas': 3}
```

This pattern of adding an element if it doesn't exist comes up frequently. You should checkout `defaultdict` in the `collections` module. If you use that, you don't even need the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through what you need to do to.  First, check if the file exists and  read the contents to a variable.  Second, parse each line - you need to split the line on the comma, convert the number from a string to an integer, and then pass the values to a dictionary.  In this case I would recommend using defaultdict from collections, but we can also do it with a standard dictionary.

```
from os.path import exists, isfile
from collections import defaultdict

filename = input("filename voor input: ")
if not isfile(filename):
    print(filename, "bestaat niet")
    exit()

# this reads the file to a list, removing newline characters
with open(filename) as f:
    line_list = [x.strip() for x in f]

# create a dictionary
my_dict = {}

# update the value in the dictionary if it already exists,
# otherwise add it to the dictionary
for line in line_list:
    k, v_str = line.split(',')
    if k in my_dict:
        my_dict[k] += int(v_str)
    else:
        my_dict[k] = int(v_str)

# print the dictionary
table_str = '{:<30}{}'
print(table_str.format('Item','Count'))
print('='*35)
for k,v in sorted(my_dict.item()):
    print(table_str.format(k,v))
```